# Encode zip file to Base64

Tags: c#, zip, base64, encode

I want decode zip file to base64 string. File can be up 100 MB and get OutOfMemory exception and restart Visual Studio. My Encode code:

```
public static string EncodeToBase64(string zipPath)
{
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(zipPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
       byte[] filebytes = new byte[fs.Length];
       fs.Read(filebytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
       return Convert.ToBase64String(filebytes);
    }
}
```

What can I do to resolve it?

Comment: 100 MB should not be a problem. Is your RAM full? Also do you need the base64 string "in code" or are you saving/sending it to somewhere?

Comment: 100MB could easily be a problem if you do it again and again

Comment: I have a lot off memory, but RAM increases rapidly when encoding to base64. base64 string I used for saving and sending

Comment: After a 32-bit program has been running for a while and got an opportunity to fragment the address space (nothing to do with RAM), allocating 90 MB can easily fail.  Well before the program is truly out of memory, there just is no hole left big enough to fit the allocation.  Otherwise a problem that's trivially solved in C# by allowing your program to run as a 64-bit process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't try to do the whole thing in one chunk.

Loop through bytes from your FileStream.  Grab multiples of three bytes and encode those.  Be sure to use a StringBuilder to build your output.

That will greatly decrease memory usage.

Answer (score 1):

*[NOTE: This answer assumes that you can process the final base 64 string in chunks, for example by writing each block in turn to a stream of some kind.]*

This is simplified if you write a helper method to read a file in `byte[]` blocks of a maximum size, e.g.:

```
public static IEnumerable<byte[]> ReadFileInBlocks(string filename, int blockSize)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[blockSize];

    using (var file = File.OpenRead(filename))
    {
        while (true)
        {
            int n = file.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

            if (n == buffer.Length)
            {
                yield return buffer;
            }
            else if (n > 0) // Must be the last block in the file (because n != buffer.Length)
            {
                Array.Resize(ref buffer, n);
                yield return buffer;         // Just this last block to return,
                break;                       // and then we're done.
            }
            else // Exactly read to end of file in previous read, so we're already done.
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can write a simple method to return a sequence of base 64 strings converted from each block of bytes from the file in turn:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> ToBase64Strings(string filename, int blockSize)
{
    return ReadFileInBlocks(filename, blockSize).Select(Convert.ToBase64String);
}
```

Then assuming you have a way of processing each converted base-64 string block, do something like this:

```
foreach (var base64String in ToBase64Strings(myFilename, 1024))
    process(base64String);
```

Alternatively, you could skip the intermediary `ReadFileInBlocks()` method and fold the conversion to base 64 string into it like so:

```
public IEnumerable<string> ConvertToBase64StringInBlocks(string filename, int blockSize)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[blockSize];

    using (var file = File.OpenRead(filename))
    {
        while (true)
        {
            int n = file.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

            if (n == 0) // Exactly read to end of file in previous read, so we're already done.
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                yield return Convert.ToBase64String(buffer, 0, n);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Matthew Watson, How can I Decode from Base64 string to zip file?